# How to call CHtml::image correctly?

Tags: php, yii

this is my code.

```
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/Images/phone.png', array('class'=>'ph1'));?>
```

i get error on code execution:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

What is the error?

Comment: above error telling that what you did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you add htmlOptions array as second parameter, while this parameter is reserved for alternative text for image. Check [documentation of `CHtml::image()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail):

> public static string image(string $src, string $alt='', array
>   $htmlOptions=array ( ))

Sou you need to specify alt parameter, for example:

```
<?php echo CHtml::image(
    Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/Images/phone.png', 
    '', // this is alt parameter; add text or leave it as empty string
    array('class'=>'ph1')
);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail) you missed the `alt` attribute:

```
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()
  ->request->baseUrl . '/images/Images/phone.png',
  'alt text', 
  array('class'=>'ph1'));
?>
```

> public static string image(string $src, string $alt='', array
>   $htmlOptions=array ( ))